# Reference request: no rest for those with ill will

Tags: reference-request, anger

I am looking for a text that I recall having seen in which the Buddha says something like: There is no rest for those who are obsessed with thoughts such as 'he has wronged/harmed me' and similar.

It may have been the Dhammapada...any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's verse 3 of [the opening chapter of the Dhammapada](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.01.budd.html),

> 1. Mind precedes all mental states. Mind is their chief; they are all mind-wrought. If with an impure mind a person speaks or acts suffering follows him like the wheel that follows the foot of the ox.
> 2. Mind precedes all mental states. Mind is their chief; they are all mind-wrought. If with a pure mind a person speaks or acts happiness follows him like his never-departing shadow.
> 3. "He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." Those who harbor such thoughts do not still their hatred.
> 4. "He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." Those who do not harbor such thoughts still their hatred.
> 5. Hatred is never appeased by hatred in this world. By non-hatred alone is hatred appeased. This is a law eternal.
> 6. There are those who do not realize that one day we all must die. But those who do realize this settle their quarrels.

Comment: Good find Chris! There's another dhammapada verse that's similar to this that the OP may find useful as well, I can't find it ATM though; its something along the lines of "emnity does not vanquish emnity. I just thought I'd throw it out there if you have a minute to link it too; I don't think it's the verse he's looking for, but its very similar in concept so I thought it might be of use :)

Comment: @Ryan I think that "emnity does not vanquish emnity" is verse 5, above.

Comment: LOL sure enough, I didn't read that far :)

Comment: @adamokkha Ven. Yuttadhammo also has translated readings of the associated stories on his YouTube channel, if you're interested :)